# Not able to update a field using Foreach in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have the following array :

```
var_dump($steps_filt);
```

Output :

```
array(2) { [0]=> string(15) "Text1" [1]=> string(23) "Text2" }
```

And the following object :

```
var_dump($step_ids);
```

```
object(Illuminate\Support\Collection)#400 (1) { ["items":protected]=> array(2) { [0]=> int(2339) [1]=> int(2340) } }
```

I'm trying to update the $step_ids fields with the $steps_filt values using the below, but I'm sure there is something wrong, since the output is incorrect :

```
   foreach($step_ids as $index => $steps_filt){

   DB::table('steps')->where('id', $step_ids)->update(['step' => $steps_filt]);

                    }
```

Comment: You send array object to the where function, but the where second arg must be string or integer! I don't know what do you do exactly. but I think you should use whereIn function instead the where.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you check the error log? It might give you an indication of what could be wrong.

But here's a possible problem: The `$step_ids` variable is a Laravel Collection. You are looping over the items in the collection, but the `DB::table('steps')->where()` call is referencing the collection instead of the current item ID (which you have named `$steps_filt`).

I think you might be misunderstanding how a `foreach` loops works in PHP. At the first iteration of the loop `$index` will be 0 and `$steps_filt` will be 2339 for example.

A naive solution to do what you want could be this:

```
$step_ids_array = $step_ids->toArray(); // Easier to work with if both are array (or collection)
for ($i = 0; $i < count($step_ids_array); ++$i) {
    $step_id = $step_ids_array[$i];
    $step_text = $steps_filt[$i];
    DB::table('steps')->where('id', $step_id)->update(['step' => $step_text]);
}
```

---

**Update**: Perhaps a bit cleaner to solve it like this:

```
$combined = $step_ids->combine($steps_filt);

// $combined will now be a collection where the keys are the IDs and the values are the texts

foreach ($combined as $step_id => $step_text) {
    DB::table('steps')->where('id', $step_id)->update(['step' => $step_text]);
}
```